# param is missing or the value is empty: credit_card(ror_ecommerce)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting the error below. I understand what the issue is, but not sure how to fix it? 
when i add credit card it says parameter is empty.
I thought I had set everything right, but I hope someone can help me find what I am doing wrong or missing, thanks!

I am getting this error:

param is missing or the value is empty::credit_card
controller:

```
class Myaccount::CreditCardsController < Myaccount::BaseController
  def index
    @credit_cards = current_user.payment_profiles
  end

  def show
    @credit_card = current_user.payment_profiles.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @credit_card = current_user.payment_profiles.new
  end

  def create
    @credit_card = current_user.payment_profiles.new(allowed_params)
    if @credit_card.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created credit card."
      redirect_to myaccount_credit_card_url(@credit_card)
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @credit_card = current_user.payment_profiles.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @credit_card = current_user.payment_profiles.find(params[:id])
    if @credit_card.update_attributes(allowed_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated credit card."
      redirect_to myaccount_credit_card_url(@credit_card)
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @credit_card = current_user.payment_profiles.find(params[:id])
    @credit_card.inactivate!
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed credit card."
    redirect_to myaccount_credit_cards_url
  end

  private

  def allowed_params
    #params.require(:payment_profile).permit!
    params.require(:credit_card).permit(:address_id, :month, :year, :cc_type, :first_name, :last_name, :card_name)
  end

  def selected_myaccount_tab(tab)
    tab == 'credit_cards'
  end
end
```

view: _form.html.erb

```
<% if @credit_card.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@credit_card.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this credit_card from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% @credit_card.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
  Please implement me!<br/>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
 <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

new.html.erb:

```
<div class='nine large-9 columns'>
  <h3> New Credit Card </h3>

  <%= form_for(@credit_card, :url => myaccount_credit_cards_path(@credit_card)) do |f| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to 'Back to List', myaccount_credit_cards_path, :class => 'button' %>
</div>
```

Comment: The error is saying that, `params.require(:credit_card)` but did not found any. Within `new` method you have `@credit_card = current_user.payment_profiles.new`. Are you sure it is correct? Shouldn't be something like `CreditCard.new`?

Comment: @blelump as i mention this code is from ror_ecommerce https://github.com/drhenner/ror_ecommerce
but when i implement it at localhost following error occurs

Comment: Notice the view stating "Please implement me!"  This implementation changes per the gateway that you choose, Hence if you choose to store your CC you need to implement this yourself.  I'd be glad to help out if you tell me the gateway you are using.

Comment: @drhenner i want to add active merchant gateway.
i successfully add API credentials into enviroment*.rb files
and added credit_card validation and credit_card method in payment_profile.rb but still shows an error

Comment: Which gateway?  Braintree? Authorize.net? Stripe?

Comment: http://cookingandcoding.com/2010/01/14/using-activemerchant-with-authorize-net-and-authorize-cim/
this link is not working and now when i submit form following error occurs:  Payment cim can't be blank